# Google earth installation problem

Tags: google-earth

I have tried to install google earth as indicated here http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Saucy_Maps_and_GPS but now I have this problem:

```
sudo dpkg -i googleearth_6.0.3.2197+1.0-1_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package googleearth.
(Reading database ... 275020 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking googleearth (from googleearth_6.0.3.2197+1.0-1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of googleearth:
 googleearth depends on ia32-libs-multiarch; however:
  Package ia32-libs-multiarch is not installed.

dpkg: error processing googleearth (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mime-support ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info ...
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 googleearth
```

what shoul I do next?

Comment: What's the output of `uname -a` command?

Comment: Linux bazil-Aspire-5741G 3.11.0-19-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 11 18:48:34 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score -1):

I installed on 13.04 using these instructions with no problems: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GoogleEarth